# Add/Update customers cart from admin

Tags: admin, addtocart

Is it possible to add/update a customers cart from admin?

```
        $productId = 700;

        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->load($productId);


        $qty = 1;
        $cart = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');


        $cart->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())->loadByCustomer($customer->getId());

        if (!$cart->getId())
        {
            $cart->assignCustomer($customer);
            $cart->save();
        }

        $info = new Varien_Object(array(
                            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                            'qty' => $qty
                        ));

        $cart->addProduct($product, $info );

        $cart->collectTotals()->save();
```

This is writing an entry into the sales_flat_quote table but it is not showing up in the customers cart. I am doing something wrong or missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
Find the customer in the backend, click on edit.
You should see a tab on the left called shopping cart. You would expect that it should work from there. But it doesn't. Or at least I didn't find a way to make it work.

But here is how I did.
Click on the 'Create order' from the customer edit screen.
Select a store view to associate the order with.
Then add to the order the products you want to put in the cart.
After adding them, you will see for each line a column named `Action`. Select from the dropdown for each product "Move to shopping cart".
Then hit "Update items and qty's".
That's it.

I know it seams like a strange process, but if you need it badly you can use it.

Comment: can you point me in the right direction where this logic is located. I wish to replicate this logic in a custom module, because I need to interact with a 3rd party datasource.

Comment: see `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController::_processActionData` specially the section that starts with `$moveItemId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('move_item');`

Comment: I have updated my post with code for my custom module. Can you have a look to see if I doing something wrong?